# Tabbed SharePoint 2010 Calendar

Tags: sharepoint-designer, calendar

I am trying to use SharePoint 2010 Calendar in a tabbed functionality using the following:

- http://www.pathtosharepoint.com/pages/easytabs.aspx
- http://erikswenson.blogspot.com/2010/04/sharepoint-tab-web-part-jquery-java-and.html

but for some reason calendar events in the tab are lining up near the month navigation which is on the top left corner. Please let me know if somebody has any alternate way. I have 10 calendars and I want to show them in a tabbed functionality.

Comment: Those links point to two different methods, which one are you using?

Comment: The two articles you reference appear to be based on SharePoint 2007 (based only on the screenshots).  The calendar has had a complete UI/Javascript overhaul since 2007.  The SharePoint 2010 calendar view, when using the SP 2010 UI, now uses alot of javascript for displaying/rendering.  You have to remember that the Calendar views were designed to work with SharePoint provided UI's, not necessarily custom UI's on top of it.  There is probably a way to get it to work, but you'll need to troubleshoot the calendar javascript (it's not documented/publicly avialable).

Comment: @Brian there's a bug in the SP2010 calendar, you'll also get the issue with the default SharePoint UI.

Comment: I am using both of the above and has the same issue. Last year I used 2007 easy tabs version and it works like a charm. But now I badly need tabs functionality in SP2010 which has some issue. I really appreciate if you have any other alternate way of providing the tab functionality for SP 2010 Calendar.

Answer (score 2):

The SharePoint 2010 calendar is buggy, and you'll certainly experience the same behavior with whatever script you use to toggle the visibility or resize it. You'll also have the issue if you do a manual browser resize btw.

If you are going to build advanced customizations, you might be better off using a third party tool like Fullcalendar.

[Update] I found a workaround that might work in your case: give your calendar Web Parts a fixed width.

Comment: @4uSharePoint see my update.

Answer (score 2):

SharePoint calendar web parts are JavaScript intensive.  EasyTabs (and others) use jQuery's hide() method which sets the CSS display property to 'none'. Unfortunately not all JavaScript operations function on hidden elements.  This is where the code is breaking.

The solution?  Use Microsoft's 'ms-hidden' class to "hide" instead.  Find the places in the EasyTabs code with `.hide()` and replace with `.addClass("ms-hidden")`.  Similarly, replace `.show()` with `.removeClass("ms-hidden")`.  That did the trick for us in SP2010 with EasyTabs.  It also works standalone as in `$("#MSOZoneCell_WebPartWPQ2").addClass("ms-hidden");` where WPQ2 is replaced with whatever web part zone you want to hide.

Comment: I've just logged on to stackexchange so I cant comment or mark as usefull but Toadmyster - you saved my life ! Your answer was really helpfull, thank you for sharing!

Comment: Great.. It's working...